# Appscale admin panel to view datastore

Tags: appscale

I have deployed my GAE application at appscale VM. The application is running correctly but i am unable to see the interface to view datastore data. As in google app engine we can view datastore by accessing the application at :8000 port. Any idea about this?

Answer (score 4):

Here is a script to enable the GAE datastore viewer on AppScale:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# author: g@appscale.com
#
# Enable the datastore viewer and reload nginx.

ALLOW=""
APPS_ID=""
IP="all"
VIEWER_PORT="8099"

usage() {
        echo
        echo "Usage: $0 [app-id ...]"
        echo
        echo "Enable the dataviewer for app-id. If no app-id is specified, enable the viewer for all apps."
        echo "WARNING: the datastore viewer is not protected! Anyone can browse your data."
        echo "WARNING: restricting by IP should be used judiciously."
        echo
        echo "Options:"
        echo "     -h        this message"
        echo "     -i <IP>   allow connections only from this IP (default is open)"
        echo
}

while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
        if [ "$1" = "-h" -o "$1" = "-help" -o "$1" = "--help" ]; then
                usage
                exit 1
        fi
    if [ -n "$1" -a "$1" = "-i" ]; then
        if [ -n "$2" ]; then
            IP="$2"
            ALLOW="allow $IP; 
      deny all;"
            shift;shift
            continue
        else
            usage
            exit 1
        fi
    fi
        if [ -n "$1" ]; then
                APPS_ID="$APPS_ID $1"
                shift
                continue
        fi
done

# Sanity checks.
if [ ! -e /etc/nginx/sites-enabled ]; then
        echo "ERROR: Cannot find nginx configurations. Is this an AppScale deployment?"
        exit 1
fi

# Get the list of running applications, and corresponding ports.
ps ax | grep appserver | grep -Ev '(grep|appscaledashboard)' | grep -- '--admin_port' | sed 's;.*--admin_port \([0-9]*\).*/var/apps/\(.*\)/app .*;\1 \2;g' | sort -ru | while read port app_id; do
        # Enable only for specified apps.
        if [ -n "$APPS_ID" ]; then
                found="no"
                for x in $APPS_ID ; do
                        if [ "$x" = "$app_id" ]; then
                                found="yes"
                                break
                        fi
                done
                if [ "$found" = "no" ]; then
                        continue
                fi
        fi

    let $((VIEWER_PORT += 1))

    # Do not apply if it's already there.
    if grep "datastore_viewer" /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/* > /dev/null ; then
        echo "Datastore viewer already enabled for $app_id."
        continue
    fi

    # Prepare the nginx config snippet.
    pippo="
upstream datastore_viewer_$VIEWER_PORT {
  server localhost:$port;
}
map \$scheme \$ssl {
    default off;
    https on;
}
server {
    listen $VIEWER_PORT;
    server_name datastore_viewer_server;
    location / {
      $ALLOW
      proxy_pass http://datastore_viewer_$VIEWER_PORT;
    }
}
"
    if [ -e /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/${app_id}.conf ]; then
        cp /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/${app_id}.conf /tmp
        echo "$pippo" >> /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/${app_id}.conf
        echo "Datastore viewer enabled for $app_id at http://$(cat /etc/appscale/my_public_ip):$VIEWER_PORT. Allowed IP: $IP."
        service nginx reload
    else
        echo "Cannot find configuration for ${app_id}."
    fi
done
```

https://github.com/AppScale/appscale/blob/master/scripts/enable-datastore-viewer.sh

Steps to implement:

1. run enable-datastore-viewer.sh from ~/
2. edit the /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/appscale-.conf file
3. look for the line that starts with: allow
4. change that IP, save the file
5. reload nginx with: service nginx reload

Answer (score 3):

The official answer is here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/appscale_community/SCr1B8eZANA
and is based on the remote_api.

If you really want the datastore viewer it is available but behind the firewall.
To expose it (warning: this path does not have authentication) you must edit the nginx configuration and reload it.

You also need to apply the following pull request:
https://github.com/AppScale/appscale/pull/1475

Add this to /usr/local/nginx/conf/sites-enabled/.conf

```
upstream datastore_viewer {
  server localhost:30000;
}
map $scheme $ssl {
    default off;
    https on;
}

server {
    listen 8090;
    server_name datastore_viewer_server;
    location / {
      proxy_pass http://datastore_viewer;
    }
}
```

And then reload nginx with:
/usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx -s reload

Now you should be able to go to your deployment on port 8090 and see the GAE console. If you do not see any entities, make sure you run the statistics generator (run daily). To generate them, go to the App Console page on the AppScale Dashboard.